# Segmentation fault bintree

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm trying to implement the bintree, but I have problems in the insert method.
If I add the first element, the program dont crash but, when I introduce 2 or more element the program crash.

This is the code

```
template <typename T>
void Arbol<T>:: insertar( T c){
    if(laraiz==0)
    {
        laraiz=new celdaArbol;
        laraiz->elemento=c;
        laraiz->padre=laraiz->hizqu=laraiz->hder=0;
    }
    else {
        celdaArbol *com=laraiz;
        bool poner=false;
        while(poner==false){
            if(c>com->elemento){
                if(com->hder==0){
                    com->hder= new celdaArbol;
                    com->hder->elemento=c;
                    com->hder->padre=com;
                    poner=true;
                }
                else{
                    com=com->hder;
                }
            }
            else {
                if(com->hizqu==0){
                    com->hizqu= new celdaArbol;
                    com->hizqu->elemento=c;
                    com->hizqu->padre=com;
                    poner=true;
                }
                else {
                    com=com->hizqu;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is in the else:

```
else{
    com=com->hizqu; //com=com->hder;
}
```

Because I saw in the debugger that the program enter several times in the section and should not do.

Comment: I think it would be much more beneficial to use English variable and type names regardless that you speak a different language... This way effectively you discourage the people who do not speak your language (spanish?) to even look at the code. Reading c++ is pretty difficult, and if this difficultness is embraced by a different language it can be very ...you know...

Comment: Why all the else's?? Use returns and continues to make the code cleaner.

Comment: Thanks you fritzone. In future I will write everything in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this code:

```
laraiz->padre=laraiz->hizqu=laraiz->hder=0;
```

You do not properly intialize pointers `hizqu` and `hder` to `nullptr` in constructor of `celdaArbol` class. And you do not initialize them in either branch of `if(c>com->elemento){` so they seem to have garbage values.

Also your code can become more readable and less error prone if you use proper C++ constructions:

```
    celdaArbol *com=laraiz;
    while( true ){
        celdaArbol *&ptr = c > com->elemento ? com->hder : com->hizqu;
        if( ptr  ) {
            com = ptr;
            continue;
        }
        ptr = new celdaArbol;
        ptr->elemento=c;
        ptr->padre=com;
        ptr->hder = ptr->hizqu = nullptr;
        break;
    }
```

This code is logically equal to yours, except it shorter, easier to read, avoid duplication and fixes your bug.

Comment: I have a problem with this code, when I try to read the element that ptr have in his father , if I insert 5,6,15  15's father is 5 not 6.
If I use debbuger, the program never enter in    if( ptr  ) {
            com = ptr;
            continue;
        }
I dont know why , because If com->hder is 6, ptr isn't nullptr

Comment: @dasavi I cannot debug your code for you, I cannot even help you as I do not see your modified code. You may copy it incorrectly or something.

Answer (score 0):

For every leaf node (except the root of the tree), you never initialize the left child or right child node to be anything but an unspecified value.

You probably meant to initialize them as `nullptr`.

Here's one example:

```
if (com->hizqu==0){
    com->hizqu = new celdaArbol;
    com->hizqu->elemento = c;
    com->hizqu->padre = com;
    poner = true;

    // What is the value of com->hizqu->hizqu?
    // What is the value of com->hizqu->hder?
}
```